# Ubuntu corrupted - cursors and scroll movement are erractic and not tocuchpad issue

Tags: 18.04, crash

I was doing some rendering on one of my old lap and I think I pushed it to the limits. Now the ubuntu behaviour is weird. Now, when I scroll, the page goes back to the top and when I type the text cursor goes back to the start. Ran a hardware diagnosis, looks like no issues in them. Also, when this happens, the system prints garbage in logs with the character ^[[H. Attached them. Please check.

[System logs screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOeUw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue. The logs in the screenshot attach was printed to the terminal using tail -f and when the it was printing the garbage character. I thought system is printing ^[[H but that was not the case.It was just the Home button was automatically pressed due to some hardware issue. That explains the moving the cursor and the scroll to the start page.

I knew ^[[ characters are typed when the a special key is pressed in terminal when an input is not expected but this did not strike as the cause and I genuinely thought I fried my processor.

Anyway I pressed the home button a few times to make sure the hardware is solved and I am not having any problem since.